# React router's warning : Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`)

Tags: reactjs, npm, router, npx

Gives a warning when I install and use the React router. Although I use the latest version of React. How can I solve this?

Comment: Show more of your code, because when you ask for help, people don't see what your problem really is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.